# Why won't a pen work on the International Space Station?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, everyday-life, free-fall, satellites

Today, in my physics class, we were discussing the effect of microgravity (specifically on the ISS) on various objects of everyday value. I learnt that a normal pen wouldn't work in space (So they designed a totally new pen ~ Fisher Space Pen).

**My Question:** Why is it so? As far as I know, a pen works on the principle: due to dynamic friction, the particles of ink or lead stick to the paper and get locked in its irregularities. So *how will a micro-g environment affect the frictional force between the pen and paper* ?

Thanking you in advance!

Comment: Related: [Can we use normal gel pens to write in zero gravity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/352831/195139) and (on skeptics.se) [Did NASA invest a million dollars in the research of a space pen, when the USSR simply used a pencil?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/12518)

Comment: Do you men any sort of pen, or just the standard ball-point pen in which gravity keeps the ink column moving down toward the pen point as ink leaves the pen?

Comment: Any sort of pen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a ball point pen, and write on a paper such that the pen is upside down (i.e, the paper is above the pen) You'll find that the pen stops working in a short while.

The pen works because gravity creates a pressure gradient which helps force out ink near the nib of the pen. When you hold the pen upside down to write / use in in space, no such pressure gradient is formed and hence the ink has no tendency to be forced/flow out of the nib.

The fisher space pen has a pressure generator (pressurized nitrogen is present in the pen which helps force the ink out, regardless of if the pen is held in any gravitational field)

(*Or they could have just used a pencil*)